# How to calculate log or exp of a value in GF(2^n) using log/exp table of GF((2^k)^m) where n=k*m?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a $GF(2^n)$ field, a $GF(2^k)$ galois fields, where $n=k \times m$ and $GF(2^k)$ is a ground field of $GF(2^n)$.

I’d appreciate pointers to papers or suggestions on:

1. How to find $\log(a)$ and $\exp(a)$ where $a$ is in $GF(2^n)$ given $\log/\exp$ look-up tables of $GF(2^k)$?
2. How to convert the values between $GF(2^n)$ into $GF\left( (2^k)^m \right)$.

Specifically I need solution for $n = 16$ (with any combination of integer $m$ and $k$, e.g. $k = 8$, $m = 2$) such that amount of calculations used for conversion is minimal. Generator polynomials for all three fields can be assumed to be known, for example for case of $n = 16$, $k = 8$, $m = 2$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&& GF(2^{16}) :     x^{16} + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 \\
&& GF(2^8) :     x^8  + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1 \\
&& GF\left( (2^8)^2 \right) :  x^2  + 3x  + 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Additional background info: Generally I have $\log$ and $\exp$ look-up tables for $GF(2^n)$ and can avoid the conversion problem all together, but $2^n$ tables don't fit into memory-constrained CPU I'm using. Thus I'm interested to calculate $\log$ and $\exp$ of $GF(2^{16})$ using $\log/\exp$ tables of $GF(2^8)$ or $GF(2^4)$. I came across this [paper](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/UT-CS-13-717.pdf), but it explicitly says that $GF(2^{km})$ is not identical to $GF \left( (2^k)^m \right)$, but doesn't offer a way to convert between the two: the result of multiplication using ground and extension fields doesn't match the multiplication result using any other method (presumably because the composite field is not identical to the original field).

Thanks in advance for any help.

p.s. same question is also posted on `math.stackexchange`, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223515/how-to-calculate-log-or-exp-of-a-value-in-gf2n-using-log-exp-table-of-gf2k).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Galois Fields, so this answer will not respond to your question directly... but I couldn't help thinking about this problem so this is what I reached (in Matlab):

```
% reduced table of logarithms (one each 256)
rd_table = [
           2
        5726
        ....
];    

two = gf(2,16);
v = gf(4, 16); 
cnt = 0; 
while length(find(rd_table == v.x)) == 0; 
    v = v * two; 
    cnt = cnt + 1; 
end; 
result = (find(rd_table == v.x)-1)*256+1-cnt
iterations = cnt
```

The idea is to find the value in the list of the logarithms; if you can't find it, left-shift the value (in GF(2^16)) and try again.

To make it work on a microcontroller you will need an `uint16` array for the 256 values in `rd_table` and an `uint8` array of 256 indices in it to speed up the lookup.

Then, to evaluate the log, you'll need up to 255 cycles (lookfor + left shift). Total complexity `O(65536/n/2logn)`, where `n` is the length of the table.

I put this code snippet on [tutorialspoint](http://goo.gl/VjSsfs) for you to play with.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate how `uint8` array of 256 indices will speed up the lookup in rd_table?

Comment: `rd_table` is not sorted (at least it is not sorted in the regular set of integers) so, to find an element in it, you should traverse the whole array. Normally this would mean an average of n/2 accesses, but, in our case, we are pretty sure (255 out of 256) that we will find nothing. So we need a way to sort the array, but we cannot do that in-place, as the index in the array is our logaritm (the most significant byte), so we can sort an array of indices so that `rd_table[indices[i]]<rd_table[indices[i+1]]`. Now we can make a binary search in the array with a worst case of `log n` accesses.